# JMeter : SOAP Message Signer Plugin

Tags: soap, jmeter, ws-security

I am trying to send a SOAP request(signed) using HTTP Request Sampler along with SOAP Message Signer plugin. Request works fine with SOAPUI. It seems to fail through JMeter if i use same parameters(for SOAP Message Signer).

As a part of SOAP Request, Header needs to be signed. I am getting the below error while Signing. Could anyone please let me know the reason for failure?

> n.c.b.j.m.AbstractWSSecurityPreProcessor: Building WSS header
>   o.a.w.d.m.WSSecSignature: Beginning signing... ERROR
>   n.c.b.j.m.AbstractWSSecurityPreProcessor:
>   org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: No certificates for
>   user "cert_alias" were found for signature

Answer (score 1):

Did you add in jmeter keystore the certificate under alias **cert_alias**?

That's what message is saying:

> No certificates for user "cert_alias" were found for signature

Keystore is located in jmeter/bin folder

You may want to try this plugin:

- https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-wssecurity/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Hi, I have placed the keystore file in the jmeter/bin folder . But it didint work. However i am specifying the file(.p12) file name in the 'SOAP Message Signer' under Certificate settings.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i was able to send a successful request using the plugin. 
I was using the Signed Header as a part of SOAP request. 
Plugin Config:
Keystore File : Path to .jks file
Keystore Password : password
Cert Alias - cert_alias
Cert Password - cert password

After removing the Signed Header from the SOAP request, it worked. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

If your SOAP endpoint expects the message to be encrypted with a client-side certificate you can configure JMeter to use it by adding the next lines to *system.properties* file:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 or jks  
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/your/jsk keystore or .p12 certificate
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your certificate or keystore password
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up.

You can also pass them via -D command line argument like:

```
jmeter -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=your-certificate.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=secret
```

More information:

- [Customizing the Default Key and Trust Stores, Store Types, and Store Passwords](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.80.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/customizingstores.html)
- [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates)

Comment: I have placed the .p12 file in the jmeter/bin folder and also specified in the system.properties file . Still fails with the same error message. Should i make any changes/parameterize the Header of the SOAP message? If i use the SOAP Message Signer plugin ,how would the header be replaced for every single request? Is there any sample test plan to refer?